# Mobius transformation, and showing it maps the unit disk D[0,1] to itself bijectively

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, mobius-transformation

Consider $a \in \mathbb{C}$, where $|a|<1$ and $f_a(z)=\frac {z-a}{1-\overline az}$.

(a) Show that $f_a(z)$ is a Mobius transformation.

(b) Show that $f_a^{-1}(z)=f_{-a}(z)$

(c) Prove that $f_a(z)$ maps the unit disks $D[0,1]$ to itself in a bijective fashion.

Answer:

(a) It can be shown that $f_a(z)$ is a Mobius transformation since $(1)(1)-(a)(\bar a)=1-a\overline a=1-|a|^2>0 \neq 0$.

(b) It can be easily shown that $f_a^{-1}(z)=f_{-a}(z)$. Consider $w=\frac {z-a}{1-\overline az}$, then $z=\frac {w+a}{1+w\overline a}$. So $f_a^{-1}(z)=\frac{z+a}{1+\overline az}$. In addition, $f_{-a}(z)=\frac {z-(-a)}{1-\overline {(-a)}z}=\frac {z+a}{1+\overline az}$. Hence $f_a^{-1}(z)=f_{-a}(z)$.

I have a problem with (c) though, as the solution provided by the lecturer is quite complicated and I feel that they should be an easier way to prove the bijectivity. The solution he provided is as follows:

Consider $|z|=r, 0 \leq r \lt 1$. Then $ \lvert \frac{w+a}{\overline aw+1} \rvert =r$ by using $f_a^{-1}(z)$. So $\lvert w+a \rvert=r\lvert \overline aw+1 \rvert$. By squaring both sides, and using properties of conjugates,
$(w+a)(\overline w+\overline a)=r^2(\overline aw+1)(\overline aw+1)$.

Expanding this would give;

$w\overline w+w\overline a+a \overline w+a\overline a=r^2(a\overline aw\overline w+\overline aw+a\overline w+1)$. By shifting the terms, we would obtain $r^2 - a\overline a=w\overline w+w\overline a+w\overline a-r^2a\overline aw\overline w-r^2\overline aw-r^2a\overline w$. By factorizing the terms, we would obtain $r^2 - \lvert a \rvert^2=(1-r^2\lvert a\rvert^2)w\overline w+\overline aw(1-r^2)+a\overline w(1-r^2)$.

Manipulating the expression (as he wanted to sue completing the square method), he will obtain
$(w+\frac{1-r^2}{1-r^2|a|^2}a)(\overline w+\frac{1-r^2}{1-r^2|a|^2}\overline a)=\frac{(r^2-|a|^2)(1-r^2|a|^2)+(1-r^2)^2|a|^2}{(1-r^2|a|^2)^2}$. $(*)$

Now just by focusing on the numerator in the right hand side of the equation;

$(r^2-|a|^2)(1-r^2|a|^2)+(1-r^2)^2|a|^2=r^2-r^4|a|^2-|a|^2+r^2|a|^4+(1-2r^2+r^4)|a|^2=r^2-r^4|a|^2-|a|^2+r^2|a|^4+|a|^2-2r^2|a|^2+|a|^2r^4=r^2-2r^2|a|^2+r^2|a|^4=r^2(1-2|a|^2+|a|^4=r^2(1-|a|^2)^2$

Plucking this expression back into the equation $(*)$, we have that

$\lvert w-(\frac{r^2-1}{1-r^2|a|^2}a) \rvert^2=\frac{r^2(1-|a|^2)^2}{(1-r^2|a|^2)^2}=(\frac{r(1-|a|^2}{1-r^2|a|^2})^2$. We can take away the squares on both sides to obtain

$\lvert w-\frac{r^2-1}{1-r^2|a|^2}a \rvert=\frac {r(1-|a|^2)}{1-r^2|a|^2}$. Then he gave a conclusion that because $0 \leq \lvert \frac{1-r^2}{1-r^2|a|^2}\rvert |a|+\frac{r(1-|a|^2)}{1-r^2|a|^2} \leq 1$, then it must be that $f_a(z)$ maps the unit disk $D[0,1]$ to itself in a bijective fashion.

I would like to ask if there are any other shorter and plausible methods in doing part (c) as I am super confused as to why he is doing such a longer method. He says that this method is one method he can think of, so I was wondering if there are indeed other methods to do so. I hope you can help me understand Complex Analysis better! Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: Expand and factor $\left|z-a|^2-\left|1-\bar{a} z|^2\right.\right.$

Comment: Sorry but which line is this from?

Comment: This is an alternative approach. Showing this expression is less than $0$ proves $\left| f_a(z) \right|<1$. It follows that $f_a$ maps $D$ into $D$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a unique Möbius transformation mapping a given set of 3 points in the extended complex plane $\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$ to another set of 3 points.

You can use that fact to show that your function maps the unit circle to itself. It might map the unit disk to the set of points outside the unit circle, but you can show that it doesn't by looking at the image of any point in the disk, say $0$.

By b), $f_a$ has an inverse, so it must be bijective. The result follows.

Comment: Sorry let me clarify some points that you mentioned. So you are implying that if there is a mapping of 3 distinct points to another 3 distinct points, then it must be a unique Möbius transformation?

Comment: I'm not quite sure about your second paragraph though. So sorry but thanks for the help

Comment: For triples of complex numbers (possibly including $\infty$) $(z_1, z_2, z_3)$ and $(w_1, w_2, w_3)$ there is a unique Möbius transformation $T(z)$ such that $T(z_i)=w_i$.

Comment: I forgot to mention another fact I used in the second paragraph: Möbius transformations map circles either to circles or to straight lines.
Since circles are uniquely specified by 3 points in the plane, it is enough to show that the images of 3 arbitrary points on the unit circle are again on the unit circle.
Tell me if you need more clarification.

Comment: I understand that circles map to circles or straight lines. Thank you! Just to add on, how do you know if the images of the 3 arbitrary points do lie on the unit circle again? How do you know it is not a bigger/small disk?

Comment: You'll have to compute the absolute value of the images of your points. If they are equal to $1$ (which they will be), then your image is the unit circle again.

Comment: Understood. But in the question above, it mentions about mapping a unit disk to itself. From what I have learnt, a disk is not the same as a circle. Hence, even if I did manage to show that the absolute value of the images are less than 1, how can I successfully prove that it indeed is the D[0,1]? (i.e. absolute value of image is less than 1 can also mean that the unit disk is being mapped onto a disk of radius 0.5 example)

Comment: Möbius transformations always have an inverse, so they are bijective. Since we already know the one in question maps the unit circle to itself, it must map the open unit disk either to itself or to ${z: |z| > 1}$. 
Any other options can be ruled out because Möbius transformations are holomorphic and, in particular, continuous (this is handwavy but can be made rigorous).

By checking what it maps, for example, 0 to, we see that it does indeed map the unit disk to itself.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!:)